# Why Google map getPlace() always returning Undefined object?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

This is the function I have used for `getPlace()` which always returning `undefined` object:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('hdnOldAddress');
var AutoCompleteAddress2;
element.value = 'Marketfair Mall 1916 Skibo Road  Fayetteville  NC 28314';

autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element);


autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', function () {
    var place2 = autocomplete2.getPlace();
    if (place2.address_components) {
        AutoCompleteAddress2 = [
            (place2.address_components[0] && place2.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[1] && place2.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[2] && place2.address_components[2].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[3] && place2.address_components[3].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[4] && place2.address_components[4].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[5] && place2.address_components[5].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[6] && place2.address_components[6].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[7] && place2.address_components[7].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[8] && place2.address_components[8].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[9] && place2.address_components[9].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[10] && place2.address_components[10].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[11] && place2.address_components[11].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[12] && place2.address_components[12].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[13] && place2.address_components[13].short_name || ''),
            (place2.address_components[14] && place2.address_components[14].short_name || ''),
        ].join(' ');
    }
});
google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete2, 'place_changed');
```

**Edit**

Replaced `this.getPlace()` with `autocomplete2.getPlace()`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Never mind, I'm wrong.  In this code, this = autocomplete2.

The issue is that place_changed is not triggered ...

---

One of the problems you encounter is that "this" is not what you want it to be.  You cannot use "this" (meaning the instance of Autocomplete) in a function that handles an event (on place_changed).  Inside those event functions the this variable means the element that was affected (clicked on, hovered over, ...)

try this:

replace var place2 = this.getPlace(); by var place2 = autocomplete2.getPlace();

Let me know if this fixed it (otherwise we need to look further)

Comment: I have tried by replace with `var place2 = autocomplete2.getPlace();` but not working. Getting same error.

Comment: We are setting value to `element`(textbox) manually rather selecting from auto suggestion dropdown provided by google map. Is that is the reason we are not getting place?

Comment: The issue is the trigger of the place_changed event.

Comment: Ah, okay.  If you set the value manually, this means place_changed is not triggered.  Could you explain what your goal is an why you do what you do?

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay, Here I am testing this address `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?libraries=places&address=Marketfair Mall, Skibo Road, Fayetteville, NC, United States` always gives me `ZERO_RESULT`. But the same address work with `Autocomplete` and place marker at appropriate place.

Comment: And hence I'm trying to passing that address to `Autocomplete` and then from returned result(address/lat and lng) show location on map.

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay, I've changed `this.getPlace()` with `autocomplete2.getPlace()` but still facing same problem.

Comment: Also notice when I'm passing address `Marketfair Mall, Skibo Road, Fayetteville, NC, United States` to `google map(https://www.google.co.in/maps/) ` it shows location but `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?libraries=‌​places&address=Marke‌​tfair Mall, Skibo Road, Fayetteville, NC, United States` always returning `ZERO_RESULT`, why this is so?

Comment: I get a result when I search for "1916 Skibo Rd #200, Fayetteville, NC 28314, USA"

Comment: Thanks very much @EmmanuelDelay I had a simlilar situation

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've used alternate to above. Instead of using `Autocomplete()` I've used `AutocompleteService()` which returns `predicted` places and using that place address I passes it to `geocoding` and the `map` shows location as expected.

```
var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
service.getPlacePredictions({ input: 'Marketfair Mall 1916 Skibo Road  Fayetteville  NC 28314' }, function (predictions, status) {                    
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        matchAddress = predictions[0].structured_formatting.secondary_text; 
        //Add further processing for geocoding for found address.
    }
});
```

Comment: This didn't completely solve my problem but helped me on the way!! So thanks!!  Essentially I replaced autocomplete with google.maps.places.

Comment: ...a more complete answer is here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817397/google-maps-api-autocomplete-getplace-inconsistently-returns-geometry/49018363#49018363