# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'geometry') - onPlaceChanged() triggering but getPlace() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, svelte, google-places-autocomplete

I am getting some errors when I click on any prediction from the google places autocomplete dropdown of predictions. From what I've discovered it getPlace() returns "undefined" the first time it's triggered, but then it returns the address the second time around.

[first click on a prediction from autocomplete dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U60M.png)

[second click on the prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOo8G.png)

[maps script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVf15.png)

[code for autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpLhB.png)

as can be seen in the code, I'm having a difficult time understanding why the getPlace doesn't return a place even though the listener triggers the onPlaceChanged(), and I'm not sure if the errors are the root of the problem, but if anyone has any clues so that i can get a different error to work with that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the logic for getting the clicked prediction and now it works correctly, thanks to the answer this question: [Google maps API autocomplete.getPlace() inconsistently returns geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817397/google-maps-api-autocomplete-getplace-inconsistently-returns-geometry/49018363#49018363)

```
let autcompleteInput: HTMLInputElement;

    function initializeAutocomplete() {
        if (autcompleteInput != null) {
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(autcompleteInput);
            searchBox.addListener('places_changed', ()=>{
                var place = searchBox.getPlaces();
                if (place) {
                    handleGooglePlacesPress(place.at(0)!)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    function handleGooglePlacesPress(details: google.maps.places.PlaceResult) {
        const addressComponents = details.address_components;
        if (addressComponents) {
            addressComponents.forEach((addressComponent) => {
                const addressType = addressComponent.types[0];
                if (addressType == 'street_number') {appartmentSuiteNum = addressComponent.long_name;}
                if (addressType == 'route') {address = addressComponent.long_name;}
                if (addressType == 'sublocality_level_1') {city = addressComponent.long_name;}
                if (addressType == 'locality') {city = addressComponent.long_name;}
                if (addressType == 'administrative_area_level_1') {county = addressComponent.long_name;}
                if (addressType == 'postal_code') {postcode = addressComponent.long_name;}
                if (addressType == 'country') {country = addressComponent.long_name;}
            });
        }
    }
```